# Responsive CSS nav behaving strangely

Tags: css, responsive-design, wordpress-theming, media-queries

I've been working on a responsive theme for my wordpress site for some time now. I am using media queries to determine screen size and adjust my layout accordingly. The problem I'm facing right now is in the header. Everything is working as expected until the screen is between 638 pixels wide and 1023 pixels wide... That's when the nav unexpectedly pops over to the side of the screen (it's supposed to be centered). The strange thing is that I do not have a media query for 638-1023. Below is the essential code but you can see all of it on my website ([digitalbrent.com](http://digitalbrent.com)). If anyone could tell me why this is happening (and I've tried it on multiple devices, so I know it's not just my screen) I'd really appreciate it. I'm not quite sure what is causing the nav to pop over like that but I need to fix it.

CSS:

```
/******************************** Medium Screen Styles */

@media screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 1023px){

    #titleBox {
        margin-top: 38px;
        width: 45%;
        margin-left: 5%;
    }

    #siteTitle {
        margin-top: 4px;
        font-size: 28px;
        width: 130px;
    }

    #tagline{
        color:#FFFFFF;
        font-family: georgia bold italic, serif bold italic;
        font-size: 18px;
        width: 210px;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

    #ctaBox{
        margin-top: 42px;
        width: 45%;
        margin-right: 5%;
    }

    #cta {
        color: #27f231;
        font-family: georgia bold italic, serif bold italic;
        font-size: 18px;
        float: left;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 50%;
        width: 224px;
        margin-left: -112px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    #phone{
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: ariel, sans-serif;
        padding: 16px 0;
    }

    #headButton{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 70%;
        max-width: 322px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #nav {
        float: left;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
        width: 300px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -150px;
    }

    #nav ul li{
        font-size: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: georgia bold italic, serif bold italic;
        color: white;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    #nav ul li:last-child{
        margin-right: 0px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
                <div id="titleBox">
                        <img id="logo" height="70" width="70" src="wp-content/themes/TesterThemeX/images/web-design.jpg" alt="Web Designer Logo - Brent Blackwood" />
                        <h1 id="siteTitle">Brent Blackwood</h1>
                        <h2 id="tagline">Web & Graphic Design</h2>
                </div>
                <div id="ctaBox">
                    <span id="cta">Call Today for a FREE Quote!</span>
                    <h2 id="phone">(801) 4-PRO-WEB</h2>
                    <div id="headButton" class="ctaButton">&nbsp;The CTA Button!&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <div id="nav" class="navScroll">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="home">
                            <div class="navIcon"></div>
                            Home
                        </li>
                        <li id="blog">
                            <div class="navIcon"></div>
                            Blog
                        </li>
                        <li id="resume">
                            <div class="navIcon"></div>
                            Resume
                        </li>
                        <li id="portfolio">
                            <div class="navIcon"></div>
                            Portfolio
                        </li>
                        <li id="lab">
                            <div class="navIcon"></div>
                            &nbsp;Lab&nbsp;
                        </li>
                        <li id="contact">
                            <div class="navIcon"></div>
                            Contact
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="clean"></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `#nav` is supposed to be centered then you'll need to:

- Replace the `float: left` with `float: none` (since you're giving `#nav` that value globally).
- Replace the `margin-left: -150px` with *(borrowing top/bottom values from your CSS)* `margin: 10px auto 12px`.

Comment: You were partially right Nils. The problem was mostly with the float. However changing the margin turned out not to be necessary. THanks for your help. I really appreciate it.